# Change scrolling direction

Tags: android

Say, a WebView with an html that scrolls vertically. What would be the basic steps to make it scroll horizontally (screen by screen)? Can't grasp the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a document that fits screen height and is wider than taller.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a [HorizontalScrollView](http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) (which was added in Android 1.5 - before that, there was no way to do this).

Comment: WebView does its own scrolling and is highly unlikely to work with HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: I agree, but this is the only way that I think it would work. Unless you can modify the HTML so that it's wide and not long, and you disable fitting to the screen, this is the only way.